# stochastic calculus - Itô formula?

Tags: itos-lemma, stochastic

I encounter a problem in the proof below:

- I don't know how to proove the first line in yellow (cf below): it makes me think about the Itô formula a lot
- I don't undertand the deduction (ok $\gamma^{\chi}$ has the constant law of a brownian motion but what does it tell us ?)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: It is indeed confusing. Some notations, for example, $\varepsilon_u^{if}
$, are used without definitions.

Comment: Yes it is I 'll come back if I have the answer. I logically think that $\epsilon_{u}^{if}=e^{\int_{0}^{u}...}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, since by definition,
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_t^{if} = e^{i \int_0^{t}f\big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_s\big)\frac{dM_s}{\sqrt{\xi}} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f\big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_s\big)\frac{d\langle M\rangle_s}{\xi}},
\end{align*}
then,
\begin{align*}
d\varepsilon_t^{if} = i \varepsilon_t^{if} f\Big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_t\Big)\frac{dM_t}{\sqrt{\xi}}.
\end{align*}
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
\langle \varepsilon_t^{if}, H_t \rangle = \int_0^t i \varepsilon_s^{if} f\Big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_s\Big) h_s \frac{d\langle M\rangle_s}{\sqrt{\xi}},
\end{align*}
as $\langle M_t, R_t \rangle = 0$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
d\big(\varepsilon_t^{if} H_t\big) &= H_t d\varepsilon_t^{if} + \varepsilon_t^{if} dH_t + d \langle \varepsilon_t^{if}, H_t \rangle\\
&= H_t d\varepsilon_t^{if} + \varepsilon_t^{if} dH_t +  i \varepsilon_t^{if} f\Big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_t\Big) h_t \frac{d\langle M\rangle_t}{\sqrt{\xi}}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\big(\varepsilon_{\infty}^{if} H_{\infty}\big) -\mathbb{E}(H_0) &=
\mathbb{E}\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}\!\!\!\! H_t d\varepsilon_t^{if} + \int_0^{\infty} \!\!\!\!\varepsilon_t^{if} dH_t + i\int_0^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\varepsilon_t^{if} f\Big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_t\Big) h_t \frac{d\langle M\rangle_t}{\sqrt{\xi}} \bigg) \\
&=i \mathbb{E}\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\varepsilon_t^{if} f\Big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_t\Big) h_t \frac{d\langle M\rangle_t}{\sqrt{\xi}} \bigg),
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\big(\varepsilon_{\infty}^{if} H\big) = \mathbb{E}(H)+i \mathbb{E}\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\varepsilon_t^{if} f\Big(\frac{1}{\xi}\langle M\rangle_t\Big) h_t \frac{d\langle M\rangle_t}{\sqrt{\xi}} \bigg).
\end{align*}